# MySQL Error Code: 1048: Column cannot be null

Tags: mysql

I have a query:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(*)
FROM
  (SELECT 
    vendors_id,
    merchants_id,
    SUM(amount) AS amount,
    SUM(commission_amount) AS commission_amount 
  FROM
    (SELECT 
      vendors_id,
      merchants_id,
      amount,
      commission_amount 
    FROM
      (SELECT 
        vendors.id AS vendors_id,
        merchants_id,
        SUM(transactions_cash.amount) AS amount,
        SUM(
          transactions_cash.commission_amount
        ) AS commission_amount 
      FROM
        ibaserver.transactions_cash,
        ibaserver.vendors,
        ibaserver.merchants 
      WHERE transactions_cash.vendors_id = vendors.id 
        AND TIME > 1466680920208 
        AND TIME <= 1466681880067 
        AND merchants_id = merchants.id 
      GROUP BY transactions_cash.merchants_id 
      ORDER BY transactions_cash.merchants_id) a 
    UNION
    ALL 
    SELECT 
      vendors_id,
      merchants_id,
      amount,
      commission_amount 
    FROM
      (SELECT 
        vendors.id AS vendors_id,
        merchants_id,
        SUM(
          transactions_cash_archive.amount
        ) AS amount,
        SUM(
          transactions_cash_archive.commission_amount
        ) AS commission_amount 
      FROM
        ibaserver.transactions_cash_archive,
        ibaserver.vendors,
        ibaserver.merchants 
      WHERE transactions_cash_archive.vendors_id = vendors.id 
        AND TIME > 1466680920208 
        AND TIME <= 1466681880067 
        AND merchants_id = merchants.id 
      GROUP BY transactions_cash_archive.merchants_id 
      ORDER BY transactions_cash_archive.merchants_id) b) s) q
```

And when the inner query

```
  SELECT 
    vendors_id,
    name,
    amount
  FROM ....
```

returns the data, the result is returned successfully. If the inner query returns only NULL:

[image: inner query result]

the entire query returns an error:

```
Error Code: 1048
Column 'vendors_id' cannot be null
```

How to return 0 in the case when the inner query returns all of a NULL?

Comment: why bother doing the sum() in the subquery, when all you want is a count() in the external query? that's a lot of extra work for the DB that's simply thrown away/ignored. why can't you have just `select count(*) from sometable`?

Comment: @MarcB, I've edited the post. I think it is not essential.

Comment: same thing holds. you're not doing anything "special" in the subquery, so you don't need it AT ALL. why can't you have `select count(*) from sometable`?

Comment: It would be helpful to see all of the code, and not just '....', as @MarcB may be right and you may not need the sub-query

Comment: @CallanHeard, I've edited the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function you want is called [COALESCE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce). COALESCE takes a list of arguments and returns the first non-NULL value from that list. For example the query

```
SELECT COALESCE(vendors_id, 0), COALESCE(name, ''), COALESCE(amount, 0)...
  FROM vendors...
```

will return either the non-NULL column value or the specified substitution value for each column.

Comment: But in this case the result will be 1... And I want to get a count of resulting rows, so it still isn't right...

Comment: I misunderstood something then. Still, you would use COALESCE at whatever point in your query the NULLs are causing problems.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function:

`ISNULL(colName,'new value') AS`

For example:

```
Select A.col1,ISNULL(B.col2,'0') as col2 from Table1 A INNER JOIN Table2 B ON A.cod1=B.cod1
```